# Vector space and cauchy and convergent sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Q: prove that every  convergent sequence is Cauchy?
From where it should be start to prove it. So much confusing.

Comment: Hint: Consider $|x_m-x_n|$ and bound it using the triangle inequality, where $x_n\to x$.

Comment: If you state the definitions, it should be intuitively clear. If $f$ gets arbitrarily close to a single point, then surely its points must eventually be arbitrarily close together.

Comment: Where to start?  From the definitions.  "Cauchy" and "convergent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose {$x_n$} is a convergent sequence such that $x_n \rightarrow x$.

This means, $\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \ N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $||x_n-x||<\epsilon,\ \forall\ n>N$

Now consider this,  for $m,n>N$,

$||x_m-x_n||= || (x_m-x)-(x_n-x)|| \leq ||x_m-x||+||x_n-x||< \epsilon +\epsilon=2\epsilon$

The 2 multiplied with $\epsilon$ does not affect the answer because it can be taken care of by taking $\frac\epsilon{2}$ at the beginning instead of $\epsilon$.

Thus, we get

$\forall \epsilon >0\ \exists\ N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $||x_m-x_n||<\epsilon\ , \forall\ m,n>N$

Hence {$x_n$} is Cauchy.